# Really, though, how can gmail still be "beta"?

Tags: gmail

- It's been out for almost five years.
- It's got tens of millions of users
- I suspect several businesses rely on it.

How is it still "beta"?  At what point will it no longer be beta?  When it completely owns the e-mail market?

Comment: Re-opened.  The definitions of "beta" are directly relevant to our field.  How one of the largest corporations in the IT world define these words has relevance.

Comment: Geez, we've got some happy trigger fingers here...

Comment: Just bored trigger happy mods.  I don't acknowledge peoples closes unless they leave a comment reasoning why.

Comment: Well, you could always do what one jerk did to me after I closed one of his questions - he found every post I'd made over a 2 week period and voted them all down.  I lost 80 rep in two days.

Comment: I have no real problem with questions being closed.  In fact, I encourage it.  However.. sometimes if it is borderline I think it would be common courtesy to explain in a little more detail the reasoning behind the close in the comments so people can discuss it.

Comment: @Paul: of course, he lost 40 over the same period.  That's part of the reason the system subtracts points for downvotes - to curb that kind of abuse.

Comment: @paul was this guys screen name by any chance jonskeet2 ? he seems to be going around everyones posts and voting them down

Comment: @Simon, you expect me to remember a username from 13 months ago?  I have enough trouble remembering the people I'm talking to right now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[According to a Google spokesman](http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/33131):

> "We have very high internal metrics
>   our consumer products have to meet
>   before coming out of beta. Our teams
>   continue to work to improve these
>   products and provide users with an
>   even better experience.  **We believe
>   beta has a different meaning when
>   applied to applications on the Web,
>   where people expect continual
>   improvements in a product.**  On the
>   Web, you don't have to wait for the
>   next version to be on the shelf or an
>   update to become available. 
>   Improvements are rolled out as they're
>   developed.  Rather than the packaged,
>   stagnant software of decades past,
>   we're moving to a world of regular
>   updates and constant feature
>   refinement where applications live in
>   the cloud."

Wikipedia defines [Beta Version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_version) as:

> A 'beta version' is the first version released outside the organization or community that develops the software, for the purpose of evaluation or real-world black/grey-box testing. The process of delivering a beta version to the users is called beta release. Beta level software generally includes all features, but may also include known issues and bugs of a less serious variety.

So this confirms that Google's use of the word is non-standard. I found this Slashdot article, [Has Google Redefined Beta?](http://tech.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=08/09/25/1235216&from=rss), to be pretty interesting.

I think Google borrowed the word for their own ends and it shouldn't be taken at face value with the traditional definition of "Beta".  It simply looks better to put "Beta" by your apps name instead of, "We are still constantly adding features to this product".

Comment: Interesting.  Though it seems to me that continuously improving your product wouldn't necessarily imply carrying the "beta" tag.  Taken literally, this would mean that all web apps should essentially always be "beta."

Comment: @JohnMcG, Yes, it does seem that would be the case.  I think Google more borrowed the word for their own purposes-meaning than anything.  Beta simply sounds better than, "We aren't done adding new features yet".

Comment: I liked the conclusion of that article, "Either that or their explanation is still in beta."

Comment: I always figured it's an easy and inexpensive safeguard against getting sued for data loss or something similar: "We said it was beta, right there on the front!"

Answer (score 3):

Well it was down for [30 hours](http://www.macworld.com/article/136216/2008/10/gmail.html) about two months ago. Looks like even after five years there are a few kinks to iron out.

Answer (score 1):

Google itself was in beta for years.  The founders have much higher standards for their products than other companies.

Answer (score 1):

Just like C++ wasn't a standard for quite a while :)
Also, they continuously add and change features, so it is a beta.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that beta, in this case, means that they are avoiding the hassles and complications of being accused of being a monopoly. Conspiracy anybody?

Comment: Gmail is far from being a monopoly. The last stats I saw (Feb 2008) showed Yahoo having over 50% of webmail market share. Hotmail/Live had 20%ish. Gmail was a distant third with 5%.

Answer (score 0):

It is (at least officially) in perpetual beta state.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_beta

Answer (score 0):

its not in beta anymore since July 2009 - so if you're seeing a 'beta' logo still its  because someone enabled the '[back to beta](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/07/gmail-leaves-beta-launches-back-to-beta.html)' feature. Yes really...

Comment: And this question was asked in December 2008, at which point it still was labeled as Beta ;-)